# Can Inferential Statistics be carried out in a Retrospective Case Study?

Tags: sample, statistical-power, inference

Just wanted to check with regard to a retrospective case study, if various data is collected for a set of patients on different variables can this be interpreted with inferential stats tests? Even if no power calculation could be made to determine the required sample size before the study began i.e. just the patients that were available with a certain pathology were used?

Many thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I think in general this is okay - there are certainly plenty of data out there that are analyzed years after collection because no one did anything with them the first time around. I think the key is to be cautious in your interpretation and clear about what your assumptions are, and checking to make sure that your assumptions make sense with the data that you have (which you should always be doing...) Given that you brought up power analysis, I would caution against drawing any inferences related to power at this point (see: [The abuse of power: The pervasive fallacy of power calculations for data analysis](http://www.vims.edu/people/hoenig_jm/pubs/hoenig2.pdf))

Comment: Many thanks, this is very helpful- could I check with you what you mean by my assumptions. Are you referring to my hypothesis? I was concerned that it is difficult to test a hypothesis when power has not been calculated and you have a very small sample size. For the sample I am measuring 14 variables so I wonder if for each a post hoc power calculation should be worked out. I think all results significant or non have to be interpreted with a cautionary approach as cause and association cannot be stated I feel in this type of design where cofounding variables are not controlled for.

Comment: Most tests have some set of assumptions associated with them. For instance, ANOVA assumes that samples are drawn from a population following a normal distribution - this is an assumption that is often not really met, but can often be be sufficiently satisfied by large sample sizes due to the central limit theorem. With n=14, you are right - I would probably not use a parametric test on these data. Retrospective =/= small sample size, hence my initial answer.

Comment: It is at least worth checking on your assumptions first before ruling them out: figure out what test you want to use, and then test the assumptions (e.g., test for normality or etc). Small or ad hoc data sets that don't meet assumptions are often very useful for exploratory data analysis, hypothesis generation and sample size calculations for later studies. I am particularly fond of ordination (PCA, etc). Even simpler techniques like boxplots and scatterplots can give you some interesting ideas about what the data might be showing without tangling you up in hypothesis testing.

Comment: As far as post hoc power calculations - please see the paper I already mentioned.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your answers, although I do not fully understand the article being a novice to statistics I believe the take home message is that there is some bias in post-hoc power calculations. I agreed with the sentiments regarding the dangers of reporting a non significant effect when one may exist, I think that is why when this is found it must be emphasised this is in the current sample.

Comment: For my testing I have mainly ordinal data and only two groups which stats can be performed on n = 10 and n = 4. Although the assumptions for a t-test were met via Shaprio-wilks and a Levene's test showing normal distribution and homogeneity of variance I decided to use the Mann-Whitney as the data is ordinal. I also had some scale data results, for these homogeneity of variance was met for 2/3 variables and the data was normally distributed so I used a t-test- perhaps I should have used M-W where for the one variable which did not have homogeneity of variances.

Comment: Thank-you again for any opinions you have. Just to note I have done lots of descriptive stats too in way of box plots which have shown differences in my groups(median scores), despite the stats tests being statistically non significant- I feel these are more meaningful to my type of study.